# Prove that dimension of $A$ is zero iff it is a field, where $A$ is an integral domain.

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain

> Let $A$ be an integral domain. Show that $\dim(A)=0 \iff A$ is a field.

The backward implication is trivial.

For the forward implication, if we can show that $1 \in <a>$, where $a(\neq 0) \in A$. Then, we are done. However, I don't know how to show it.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Any unital ring has a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 5):

Since maximal ideals are prime, "zero-dimensional" becomes the same thing as "prime ideals are maximal ideals."

In a domain $\{0\}$ is prime, and in a zero-dimensional domain it is also maximal.

So, there are no other ideals besides $\{0\}$ and $A$. Do you know what this implies about $A$? (There are already more than one question on the site answering this, if you formulate the correct question...)

Answer (score 1):

This means $(0)$ is the only prime ideal, since $A$ is a domain. As the set of non-invertible elements is the union  of all prime/maximal ideals, it implies all non-zero elements are invertible.

Comment: Could you explain why the set of non-invertible elements is the union of all prime ideals?

Comment: It is just because the ideal generated by an invertible element contains $1$ and by definition, a prime ideal is $\neq A$. Hence an invertible element cannot belong to a prime ideal.

Comment: But I didn't get how, an invertible element cannot belong to a prime ideal $\implies$ the set of non-invertible elements is the union of all prime ideals. How are we using the property of Integral Domain?

Comment: @chi The missing step is essentially the hint I wrote in a comment.